# Drupal Commons 7.x-3.29 Front page Create a post

Tags: 7

Create a post was a smallish box before 7.x-3.29.  You could click "go to full form" to get more options for your post.  Now it shows media attachment and group selection dialog which takes up a lot of the front page.  Can it be changed back to the way it was or eliminated from the front page?  Suggestions appreciated.